# Start KDE 5 Plasma with nouveau.noaccel=1 (no 3D acceleration)

Tags: kde, nvidia, plasma, nouveau

I am tired of nouveau freeze and lockups. But don't want to switch to shitty nvidia binary driver. So I decided to disable any 3D acceleration, I don't need it. I have already configured XRender as my compositor, but when I boot with nouveau.noaccel=1, after login on sddm, kde don't start. Segmentation fault on /usr/lib64/libexec/kf5/kscreen_backend_launcher.

Please help me totally disabling any acceleration in KDE PLasma 5.9.3